# Is having too many url rewrites in my htaccess a bad thing?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am new to url rewriting. My htaccess file has about 20 rewrites so far and more to come. I am curious if the more I have, will it slow my page load or anything of the sort?

I am trying my best to structure my urls so I can have minimal rewrites but I am not sure if I have already failed by having 20 already.

```
RewriteRule ^account/(\w+)(.*)$ ./index.php?option=account&task=$1 [L,PT]

# Auth Controller
RewriteRule ^auth/(\w+)(.*)$ ./index.php?option=auth&task=$1 [L,PT]

# Collections Controller
RewriteRule ^collections(.*)$ ./index.php?option=collections [L,PT]
RewriteRule ^collections/(\w+)(.*)$ ./index.php?option=collections&task=$1 [L,PT]

# Friends Controller
RewriteRule ^friends/(\w+)(.*)$ ./index.php?option=friends&task=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L,PT]

# Index Controller
RewriteRule ^index(.?)$ ./index.php?%{QUERY_STRING} [L,PT]
RewriteRule ^index/index(.?)$ ./index.php?%{QUERY_STRING} [L,PT]
RewriteRule ^about(.*)$ ./index.php?option=index&task=about [L,PT]
RewriteRule ^ideas(.*)$ ./index.php?option=index&task=ideas [L,PT]
RewriteRule ^contact(.*)$ ./index.php?option=index&task=contact [L,PT]
RewriteRule ^faq(.*)$ ./index.php?option=index&task=faq [L,PT]

# Messages Controller
#RewriteRule ^messages/(\d+)(.*)$ ./index.php?option=messages&account_id=$1 [L,PT]

# Run Controller
RewriteRule ^run/(\d+)(.*)$ ./index.php?option=run&account_id=$1 [L,PT]

# Stores Controller
RewriteRule ^stores/(\w+)(.?)$ ./index.php?option=stores&task=$1 [L,PT]
```

Comment: Why do you have 20?  I have yet to see a config that needs more than 2 or 3.  Show us what you have.

Comment: @Brad: if you haven't seen that config - it doesn't mean it is pointless. In our big projects we have dozens of rules (for up to hundred or more).

Comment: I'm sure there are better ways I am unaware of. It's only 14 so far but I do have more. I think my main problem is the use of query strings. When should they become part of the new URL or just bet left as a query string?

Comment: Good question, though I would have to guess that it is faster for Apache to perform rewrite rules than what might be the alternative in your situation = have PHP gather (more) complex parameters and decide where to pass control.

Comment: @Justin Carlson: what's wrong with query strings? You don't like `%{QUERY_STRING}`? Then just use `[QSA]` modifier

Comment: @ghbarratt: are we discussing performance or what? From performance point of view apache's mod_rewrite always faster than moving rules to php.

Comment: @zerkms, I wasn't trying to imply it was pointless, but since he hadn't posted it, I was expecting he explicitly pointed every URL to something.  Turns out that was true, and this can be very unmanageable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically `.htaccess` does slow down Apache but in reality the performance penalty is minuscule. Do not worry about having too many rewrites simply because of performance issues.

Further reading: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/21055/alternative-to-htaccess-due-to-bad-performance

But as Brad said, 20 rewrites sounds like a lot. I would condense them simply for readability purposes because it can get difficult to debug which rule does what when you have 20 rules on top of each other.

Comment: omg, guys, how much is not a *lot*? Currently I'm looking at `.htaccess` with 292 lines of one of really big projects.

Comment: @zerkms Alot is subjective, but to me I'd say most people don't need more than 10. The only exception I see is if your manually rewriting every URL to another URL (ie no regex, just somefile.html -> dir/dir2/otherfile.html)

Comment: @zerkms For reference the drupal project (http://drupal.org), a fairly huge project, has ~15 rewrite rules, and that's with half of them dealing with compressed cached files. The entire thing minus comments is 45 lines, with most of them configuring non-rewrite things like php and caching, all to get Drupal to the same common denominator. So in short, very few rules are actually needed to get work done

Comment: Well thanks a lot guys for the advice. I did find a better way to condense what I had into 4 rewrites.

Answer (score 0):

Not really. If you have the ability to put them in the Apache configuration itself, they won't have to be reloaded with every request.